# how to use pynetfilter_conntrack library of python

Tags: python, tcp, netfilter

I am trying to write a python program for listing established TCP connections. I found pynetfilter_conntrack module. I have installed using `pip install pynetfilter_conntrack`. while importing the library I got error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pynetfilter_conntrack/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pynetfilter_conntrack.func import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pynetfilter_conntrack/func.py", line 6, in <module>
    library = cdll.LoadLibrary("libnetfilter_conntrack.so.1")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libnetfilter_conntrack.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And fixed using command

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/lib/libnetfilter_conntrack.so.3.1.3 /usr/lib/libnetfilter_conntrack.so.1
```

I searched, but I could not get document on how to use it with some example program. Also it's wiki site is currently down.

`http://software.inl.fr/trac/trac.cgi/wiki/pynetfilter_conntrack.`

Comment: [Questioning](https://github.com/regit/pynetfilter_conntrack/issues/2) the same. Currently got 0.4.2 working at the moment (0.5 - not). There is a [github repo](https://github.com/regit/pynetfilter_conntrack), but I don't know wheather is it official or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web page is down [due the finishing of sponsored development](https://github.com/regit/pynetfilter_conntrack/issues/2#issuecomment-118876377). But there is a [new maintainer](https://github.com/regit/pynetfilter_conntrack/) on github trying to prevent the final death of the library.

As I see this repo (0.5) version is currently in development, but got an a [example](https://github.com/regit/pynetfilter_conntrack/blob/master/conntrack.py) which will give you the key idea of using even 0.4.2 version.

```py
from netifaces AF_INET
import pynetfilter_conntrack

# Print source ip, port and sent bytes
ct = pynetfilter_conntrack.Conntrack()
for item in ct.dump_table(AF_INET):
    print item.orig_ipv4_src, item.orig_port_src, item.repl_counter_bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's answer was really helpfull. But unfortunatly that didn't work for me. So, I googled and modified little bit of above code(May be different versions of `pynetfilter_conntrack`).

```
import netifaces
import pynetfilter_conntrack

# Print source ip, port and sent bytes
ct = pynetfilter_conntrack.Conntrack()
'''
ct.dump_table(netifaces.AF_INET)--> returns the 2 values of tuple. one is list of objects and another is number of connections I guess. So the bellow change
'''
for item in ct.dump_table(netifaces.AF_INET)[0]:
   print item.orig_ipv4_src, item.orig_port_src, item.repl_counter_bytes
```

Thanks!